# Flask SQLAlchemy does not update models foreign keys automatically

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

So I am trying to make a simple Blog web app with flask and flask-sqlalchemy with PostgreSQL.
There is a core directory, that consists of **init**, models and views python files.
models.py looks like this:

```
from core import db
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    surname = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    nickname = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)

    posts = relationship("Post", back_populates="user")


class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)
    time = db.Column(db.Time, nullable=False)
    text = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"), nullable=False)

    user = relationship("User", uselist=False, back_populates="posts")
```

**init**.py looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from settings import DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f"postgresql://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASSWORD}@localhost:5432/test"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy()
db.init_app(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

from core import views
```

and views.py is this:

```
from core import app
from core import models


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello world ^_^!!!"
```

I applied all database migrations, the two tables 'users' and 'posts' were created.
I then try to add a user and a post via flask shell. I run:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> u = User(name='Bob', surname='Fisher', nickname='bobby1337', email='whatever@example.com')
>>> p = Post(date=datetime.datetime.now().date(), time=datetime.datetime.now().time(), text="Hello! This is the first post ever!", user_id=u.id)
>>> print(u.id)
None
>>> print (p.id)
None
>>> print(p.user_id)
None
>>> 
>>> print(u.posts)
[]
>>> print(p.user)
None
```

I then thought, maybe I need to commit changes in order for everything to work properly, so i ran:

```
>>> db.session.add(u)
>>> db.session.add(p)
>>> db.session.commit()
```

and indeed, u.id and p.id were set, but p.user_id, p.user and u.posts are still empty:

```
>>> print(u.id)
1
>>> print (p.id)
1
>>> print(p.user_id)
None
>>> print(p.user)
None
>>> print(u.posts)
[]
```

*and user_id field in the actual database was also empty, even thought `nullable=False` was set in the model.*
Now, **what am i missing here?**. I thought, SQLAlchemy should do this automatically, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The id is not assigned until the user is added to the session and then committed. In your case, no id is specified during the assignment of the id to the ForeignKey, so the relationship does not work.

I recommend the following procedure. Here the user is assigned to the relationship attribute `user` of the post. In this case, the user is automatically committed along with the post.

```py
u = User(
    name='Bob', 
    surname='Fisher', 
    nickname='bobby1337', 
    email='whatever@example.com'
)
p = Post(
    date=datetime.datetime.now().date(), 
    time=datetime.datetime.now().time(), 
    text="Hello! This is the first post ever!", 
    user=u
)
db.session.add(p)
db.session.commit()
```